# Angularjs $rootScope.$broadcast when watch position to pass message from factory to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gps

I want to create factory which will navigator.geolocation.watchPosition and everytime will broadcast to rootscope then directive will listen $scope.$on. Is there any performance issue on the way or better how way to do it? The device with this app will be on the always on the move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcast is always heavy. 
Instead of broadcast, emit on the rootScope and listen on the rootScope. And when your directive scope is destroyed remove the listener from the scope.

**Factory:**

`$rootScope.$emit('eventName:emit');`

**Directive:**

```
var destroyFn = $rootScope.$on('eventName:emit', listernFn);
$scope.$on('$destroy', destroyFn);
```

Changed name `eventname` to `eventname:emit` to make event specific to listen `$emit` event.

Comment: @pankajparkar,it will work because we are listening on the rootScope itself.
emit will trigger the listeners on the scope on which it is emitted and the parent scopes of it.

Comment: @VinayK thats but that will listen both, $boradcast or $emit of same event name

Comment: @pankajparkar, True. If we $broadcast from the $rootScope it will listen will listen for it as well.

Comment: Agreed. +1 & made edit to listen only `$emit` event by adding `:emit` in event, that make more readable code. Thanks